# A strange thing about highlight warning message

Tags: vim

I use [ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) to have a syntax checking and customize its warning message with unicode :orange_diamond:. However, within a same file, the chars :orange_diamond: have a different background color:

Most are expected:

[image: normal]

Only one is abnormal, which half of background color is darker.

[image: unexpected]

The problem also occurs in statusline, whose background color is 238.

[image: statusline]

I have tried SignColumn, SpacialChar as well as some other suspected entries in colorscheme. What's more, I use terminal vim and guess the darker color is 16 or 232 in 256 colors, for the normal background color is 234.

Is There anything wrong with the unicode char in vim ?

Comment: Looks more like a terminal/font problem. The emojis you're using aren't the same width as the rest of the font (e.g. not monospaced) and most (almost all) terminals can't really handle that. I think these are loaded from a fallback font and not the main one? Don't think there's a whole lot you can do except change the font to one which supports those emojis.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I have tried many other fonts, both powerline fonts and macOS default ones. None of them could solve the problem. Is there no fonts to cover this?

Comment: Many monospace fonts don't include emojis, or don't include many, so your terminal is looking for other fonts that *do* have these glyphs – which seem to be non-emoji fonts. I'm reasonably – though not 100% – sure that this is the problem. The solution is simple: don't use these emojis but a character your font supports.